# Not able to integrate $ \int \frac{\sin x}{\sin x + \cos x} \ dx $ ??

Tags: indefinite-integrals

$$
\int \frac{\sin x}{\sin x + \cos x} \ dx
$$

So what I thought of doing was converting $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ into $\tan\frac{x}{2}$

But it got converted into non integrable form

Any other methods would be appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $$I=\int \frac {\sin x}{\sin x+\cos x}dx$$
And $$J=\int \frac {\cos x}{\sin x+\cos x}dx$$

$J+I$ is pretty easy.  For $J-I$ put $\sin x+\cos x= u$ to get numerator of $J-I$ as $du$